# my end goal is to see end of month data for previous month

Tags: sql

My end goal is to see end of month data for previous month.
Our processing is a day behind so if today is 7/28/2021 our Process date is 7/27/2021

So, I want my data to be grouped.

[image]

```
DECLARE 
@ProcessDate INT 

SET @ProcessDate = (SELECT [PrevMonthEnddatekey] FROM dbo.dimdate WHERE datekey = (SELECT  [datekey]  FROM sometable [vwProcessDate]))
SELECT
      ProcessDate
    , LoanOrigRiskGrade 
      ,SUM(LoanOriginalBalance) AS LoanOrigBalance
      ,Count(LoanID) as CountofLoanID
FROM SomeTable
WHERE
     ProcessDate in (20210131, 20210228,20210331, 20210430, 20210531, 20210630)
```

I do not want to hard code these dates into my WHERE statement. I have attached a sample of my results.
I am GROUPING BY ProcessDate, LoanOrigRiskGrade
Then ORDERING BY ProcessDate, LoanOrigIRskGrade

Comment: So are you trying to see the months prior by month?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. I’m not clear what your comment about processing being a day behind has to do with anything? Do you just want to select records where the ProcessDate is the last day of the month?

Comment: @briskovich - Yes I simply do not want to hard code  my 
WHERE (Statement to say hey run the data for these 6months and bring back the results)
ProcessDate in (20210131, 20210228,20210331, 20210430, 20210531, 20210630)
so even if i run my report today which is 7/29/2021 my report should only show me data as of 6/30/2021. Looks like Dougp has responded with a query. I have yet to test it.

Comment: @NickW - Do you just want to select records where the ProcessDate is the last day of Previous month? So, if I run my report today which is 7/29/2021 my report should only show me data as of 6/30/2021 for anything that was processed from 6/1/2021 to 6/30/2021 - hope that helps !! and once thank you so much for responding promptly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the last day of the month for months within a specified range.  You can parameterize that.

For SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @ProcessDate INT 

SET @ProcessDate = (
    SELECT [PrevMonthEnddatekey] 
    FROM dbo.dimdate 
    WHERE datekey = (
        SELECT  [datekey]  
        FROM sometable [vwProcessDate]
    )
)

DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE
SET @startDate = '2021-01-01'
SET @endDate = '2021-06-30'

;
with d (dt, eom) as (
  select @startDate
  , convert(int, replace(convert(varchar(10), eomonth(@startDate), 102), '.', ''))

  union all
  select dateadd(month, 1, dt)
  , eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, dt))
  from d
  where dateadd(month, 1, dt) < @endDate
)

SELECT ProcessDate
, LoanOrigRiskGrade 
, SUM(LoanOriginalBalance) AS LoanOrigBalance
, Count(LoanID) as CountofLoanID

FROM SomeTable
  inner join d on d.eom = SomeTable.ProcessDate
```

Difficult to check without sample data.

Comment: Hey @dougp , First off thank you for promptly providing me a query feedback. I did plug in your query but got an error as shown below: 

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Completion time: 2021-07-29T12:29:38.1546851-04:00

Comment: Why is `@ProcessDate` an `int`?

Comment: I updated my answer, but without knowing which RDBMS you are using and having the structure of the data and some sample data, I can't test.